# K-means algorithm suitable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis

I am writing a python script to analyse some data captured from a device. I want to automate the task of finding out if my data matches a certain pattern. In the image given below I want to determine that in the given set of captured data if I can categorize my data into 3 different clusters [as shown] using a script. The range of these clusters are not predefined. All I want to know is if I see a three different clusters in my data that are reasonably apart from each other - if not then my test fails. I am just trying to figure out what is best data analysis algorithm to use here. I was reading about clustering algorithms and was going to start with K-means clustering but anyone has a better idea?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1EGh.jpg
[Link to the an example set of captured data - Note the color coded clusters][1]

Answer (score 0):

The better idea is to **start with a good problem statement**. If you are not able to strictly define what you are looking for, then no method is suitable. If you can exactly write down what you need, then you can search for a solution. Clustering methods are quite weird objects, they will always "succeed", they will always cluster your data, often in a way, which is completely unacceptable for a human being. If your data looks like you plotted (it is 2d case, with points being a parts of a "dense" point clouds) then the most appropriate seems something like DBScan/Optics, so very simple method, which will result in more "human like" clusters (as opposed to k-means which won't divide your data into those "clouds", but rather will often split them).